# On-premises Data Gateway Compatibility with Azure ExpressRoute

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, express-router, data-gateway

I've been reviewing the documentation and haven't found the answer. Hoping someone will be able to assist here.

We have an on-prem network that connects to an Azure tenant via ExpressRoute.
We want to deploy an On-Premises Data Gateway to leverage Power BI from our Azure tenant.

Will the Data Gateway have issues connecting to the service bus if it has to traverse the ExpressRoute to reach Azure?

Unfortunately, we are unable to test this due to our cost management policies. No testing has been done at this time. Only a review of on-prem data gateway documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the PBI Gateway will use your organization's network and if the machine running the Power BI Gateway is connected to the ExpressRoute, the data will transfer between the on-premises data sources and Azure services (including Power BI) and will utilize the dedicated ExpressRoute connection.
Testing wise, there should be no cost issues in running it. If you can you can use the personal gateway installed on you local machine (if you have permission to install programs), or just install the gateway on a test machine. It's free and can be uninstalled.